# How can i create this kind of slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

[I want to do like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVC1v.jpg)

I am having problem to make this kind of slider.

Here is my html Code:

```
<div class="recent-post">
    <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
    <a class="next" href="#"></a>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo.jpg">
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo2.jpg">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo3.jpg">
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo4.jpg">
        <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo5.jpg">
        <p>Content 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo6.jpg">
        <p>Content 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo7.jpg">
        <p>Content 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo8.jpg">
        <p>Content 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find any slider like this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any jquery content/image slider could do that easily. I would suggest experimenting with a few sliders to see what works best for you. Just because you didn't find that particular examples doesn't mean that it's not achievable. Try out a few things for yourself and come back with what you tried if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks i will try again to customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put whatever content into the slides of any standard slider plugin (which accepts HTML). Just group the HTML elements together and put them into the sliding element. The slider should treat .slide as slide ofc.

```
<div class="recent-post">
    <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
    <a class="next" href="#"></a>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo.jpg">
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo2.jpg">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo3.jpg">
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo4.jpg">
        <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo5.jpg">
        <p>Content 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo6.jpg">
        <p>Content 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo7.jpg">
        <p>Content 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="photo8.jpg">
        <p>Content 8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give me a demo link so that i can understand clearly how to create like this.

Comment: It depends on your slider. You could use http://bxslider.com/ for instance. As you can see within the documentation <li></li> can contain arbitrary HTML. Therefore <div class="slide"></div> would be <li></li> within the context of bxslider.

Comment: I don't want to slide all. i just want slide first 4 div then next 4 dive then next 3 div etc.

Comment: Thats what you can do if you properly set up your HTML